# how to animate a rope using canvas or css3

Tags: html, ipad, css, canvas, jquery-animate

I want to dive in the canvas animation (or if it's possible with css3, its also an option).
I want to (automatically) animate this rope (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRNZk.jpg), like its dangling around a bit. I tried looking for a script or other solutions but cant seem to find e proper one. Is it possible to have it fixed in the top of the rope and the pricetag rotates a bit at the bottom?

Can someone tell me where i can start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start see inverse kinematics (IK) and in particular inverse kinematics for chains:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_kinematics

This page has a live example in JavaScript showing the basics.You can use this to get the end-point floating around which would affect the rest of the segments:
http://www.lorenzonuvoletta.com/tag/inverse-kinematics/

As well as here:
http://hw.hawkguide.com/works/ikv3/ik.html

There are many resources about this out there, here are some papers on the topic:

- http://www.roboticsproceedings.org/rss02/p23.pdf
- http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs273/scribing/scribe4.pdf